# Can't add a throws clause to overridden method causing me to have to return null

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, polymorphism

I am currently working with an AsyncTask and in the `doInBackground` method runs a piece of code which requires a certain exception to be handled. Since the `doInBackground` method is overridden, I can't add a throws clause to the method. I have inserted a try-catch method which catches the exception but since my method returns a Summoner object, I had to include a `return null;` statement and I find my code still executing this statement.

My experience with AsyncTask is pretty limited so if you require more information or I'm overlooking something here, feel free to point it out.

```
public class GetSummonerData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Summoner>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        button.setText("Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Summoner doInBackground(String... asyncParams)
    {
        try
        {
            String summonerName = asyncParams[1];
            RiotApi api = new RiotApi("api-key");
            Map<String, Summoner> summoners = null;

            //The following line of code will call the API 
            summoners = api.getSummonersByName(Region.valueOf(asyncParams[0]), summonerName);
            //stage 1
            return summoners.get(summonerName);
        }
        catch (RiotApiException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Summoner result)
    {
        //stage 2
        startNewIntent(result);
    }
}
public void startNewIntent(Summoner summoner)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("summoner", summoner);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

At stage 1, the `summoners` variable holds 1 Summoner object. At stage 2 the returned result in `onPostExecute` equals null. Why is the return null executed even though there is a return statement within the try block?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking for an explanation why it still executes the return null statement after a result has already been returned earlier in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `return null` is executed is because an exception has been thrown during the `try-catch` block. This causes all remaining execution of the `try` block to be aborted (including the return statement) and the `catch` block to be executed instead.

Once the catch block exits the `return null` after it is then executed since execution continues as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code:

```
public class Class1 {
public Class1() {
    super();
}
public String fetchString(int i) {
    try {
        int j = 1/i;
        return "passed";
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    System.out.println(class1.fetchString(1));
    System.out.println(class1.fetchString(0));
  }
}
```

You will realize that when exception is thrown, it is caught, and hence the return statement in "Try" block is never called/executed. (exception is thrown at 1/i when i =0).

Same is happening with your code.

Regarding your other observation, you can't add any new exception to the method you are implementing of interface. Check following example.

```
public interface myinterface
{
  public void foo();
}
```

Now consider this

```
public class Ximpl implements myinterface
{
    public void foo() throws IOException
    {
    }
 }
```

Now if client has a code like

```
 myinterface varx = new Ximpl();
  //he can do that 
  varx.foo(); //without putting it in try catch block. (Remember polymorphism)??
```

If you really want to throw an exception in catch block, create an instance of Runtime Exception, which need not to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick, Wrap the exception in a RuntimeException and rethrow it. Like this

```
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(""));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```

In this way you don't need to return null.

You can even create your own version of exception that extends RuntimeException. That way you don't need to add it to method signatures and don't force other to catch it. Just like this

```
    public class MyValidationException extends RuntimeException {

    }
```

Comment: While this works in this case it's not a great idea as a general case. Checked exceptions exist for a reason and this is just bypassing them.